# Rename files in directory according to name of directory

Tags: shell, files, rename

I am trying to rename a bunch of files according to the names of their directory in Linux, SSH.

I have a directory called `XYZ01smith`. In it are four files called `smith_5*`.I need to add prefix `XYZ01` to these files.
**But**, the next directory is called `XYZ02perry`. In it are four files called `perry_3*`. I need to add the prefix `XYZ02` to these files.

I have a loop to do this per directory:

```
for i in smith_5*;
    do mv ${i} XYZ01${i};
done
```

But I have 50 directories (`XYZ01name` to `XYZ50name`), so I would rather be able to do this with one script for all 50. I am sure this should be possible, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(XYZ??)(*)/(*)' '$1$2/$1$3'
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do this with ssh?

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`:

```
for f in XYZ*/*; do mv -v "$f" "${f%/*}/${f:0:5}${f##*/}"; done
```

The `for` loop runs trough all `XYZ*` directories. Then the `mv` command renames the files.

Where:

- `$f` is the original filename
- `${f%/*}` is the directory name
- `${f:0:5}` is the prefix
- `${f##*/}` is the original filename

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command which just shows you what it would do:

```
ls -d XYZ*/* |
sed -n s'|\(XYZ[0-9][0-9]\)\([^/]*\)/\(\2_.*\)|mv & \1\2/\1\3|p' |
cat
```

and if you like the commands to run, replace `cat` by `sh`.